# Prove $|f'(z)|\leq\frac{Re(f(z))}{Re(z)}$ for all $z$ in the right half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reviewing complex analysis for the final exam, but I am stuck in this question without any ideas...

Let $D=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|Re(z)>0\}$ and $f:D\rightarrow D$ a holomorphic function.

Prove that $|f'(z)|\leq\frac{Re(f(z))}{Re(z)}$ for all $z\in D$

I have tried many things.

Firstly, I tried to use Cauchy's inequality. We could find a disc centered at $z_{r}$ with radius $r$ such that $|Re(z_{r})-0|<r$. However, it is hard for me to even find $sup_{z\in D_{r}(z_{r})}|f(z)|$. Then, it is even hard to find the real part of $f(z)$ under this formula.

Secondly, I tried to use conformal map $F(T_{1}(f(z)))$ where $T_{1}(z)=iz$ and $F(z)=\frac{i-z}{i+z}$. Clearly $T_{1}(z)$ is the rotation conformally mapping the right half plane to the upper half plane, and $F(z)$ is the standard conformal map mapping the upper half plane to the unit disc. Then, I tried to apply Cauchy's inequality to the composition map, but I got stuck.

I have no idea about how to solve this question.

I am really really grateful for any hints and explanations!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. Just need to turn to [Schwarz lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma) for help.

For the sake of convention, I will use $\mathbb{H}$ to denote your domain $D$, i.e., the right half plane, and $\mathbb{D}$ to denote the unit disk.

Define
$$
T_{z_0}:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{D},\quad z\mapsto\frac{z-z_0}{z+\overline{z_0}},
$$
which maps $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$ to $0\in\mathbb{D}$. Obviously, its inverse reads
$$
T_{z_0}^{-1}:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{H},\quad z\mapsto\frac{z_0+\overline{z_0}z}{1-z},
$$
which maps $0\in\mathbb{D}$ to $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$.

Consider the composition (where $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$ is a fixed parameter)
$$
g=T_{f(z_0)}\circ f\circ T_{z_0}^{-1}:\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D},
$$
which maps $0\in\mathbb{D}$ to $0\in\mathbb{D}$. Thanks to this fact, together with that $g$ is obviously holomorphic, Schwarz lemma applies. Therefore,
$$
\left|g'(z)\right|\le 1
$$
holds for all $z\in\mathbb{D}$. Specifically, since $0\in\mathbb{D}$, we have
$$
\left|g'(0)\right|\le 1.
$$
This inequality suffices to complete this proof.

The rest of this proof involves tedious calculation, caused by the complexity of
$$
g(z)=T_{f(z_0)}\circ f\circ T_{z_0}^{-1}(z)=\frac{f\Bigl(\frac{z_0+\overline{z_0}z}{1-z}\Bigr)-f(z_0)}{f\Bigl(\frac{z_0+\overline{z_0}z}{1-z}\Bigr)+\overline{f(z_0)}}.
$$
Nevertheless, as you carry out each step carefully, you will eventually obtain that
$$
\left|g'(0)\right|\le 1\iff\left|f'(z_0)\right|\le\frac{\Re\left(f(z_0)\right)}{\Re\left(z_0\right)}.
$$
Finally, thanks to the arbitrariness of $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$, it is an immediate result that
$$
\left|f'(z)\right|\le\frac{\Re\left(f(z)\right)}{\Re\left(z\right)}
$$
holds for all $z\in\mathbb{H}$.

Hope this could be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you so much! Make great sense to me!

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: My pleasure. Hope I did not skip calculation details therein. I carried them out on my scratched paper, but decided to leave them aside as there are so many horrible fractions... Good luck to you :-)

Comment: I have figured this question out following your solution! Thank you! I have one more questions, how do you derive the conformal map at the very beginning? I tried to use the conformal maps from Stein's book but they cannot help me finish this question. Where did you get the inspiration of the conformal map?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: No problem! For conformal mappings and holomorphic automorphism, maybe you could drop an eye on [J.W. Brown's Complex Variables and Applications](https://scholar.google.com.sg/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Complex+Variables+and+Applications+%5BBrown%5D&btnG=). Chapters 8 and 9 therein would help you in a systematical fashion (textbook-level classics), while Chapter 11 goes to advanced topics that are extremely useful in practice (especially in engineering). Chapter 10 provides typical examples for theoretical analyses, not meant for practical applications though.

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: One more comment is that, if your target is on the exercise questions, these four types of bi-holomorphic conformal mappings are crucial: $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{D}$, $\mathbb{D}\to\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{D}$ and $\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$. They are all Mobius transforms. Here bi-holomorphic means these mappings are bijective. While in your question, the mapping $f:\mathbb{H}\to\mathbb{H}$ is not necessarily surjective, i.e., $f(\mathbb{H})\ne\mathbb{H}$.